# How Can I dynamically create objects in C# Type and Name

Tags: c#, linq, list, dynamically-generated

[image]

I want to create a list of dynamically created objects.

Then I want to add this object to a list.

So in the Above example I would like to create a list of type entity with a name of Image

```
        List<DataConsistencyModel> dataConsistencyModels = new List<DataConsistencyModel>
        {
              new DataConsistencyModel{   PropertyName = "Logo",TypeOf = typeof (Entity),ValidFunction =  x => x.GroupId == null},                      
        };

        foreach (DataConsistencyModel dcm in dataConsistencyModels)
        {

            List<TypeOf> PropertyName = Data.Where(dcm.ValidFunction).ToList();

        }
```

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of code. Paste the actual code here.

Comment: `var list = Data.Where(dcm.ValidFunction).ToList();` ?? but this is just implicit typing by compiler.

Comment: Are all the dynamically created objects of the same "type"? If so you could use anonymous objects. If not you could use a List<Object> and ExpandoObjects.

Comment: @Mant101 They won't be of the same type I'm just trying to get one type working first.

Comment: First, you haven't declared a name for your variable in your foreach. Second, what's your problem exactly ?

Comment: @cosmo0 I want to create a list of variables of type `Entity` called Logo in the `Foreach` loop

Comment: there is also    dynamic instead of var

Comment: Yes but you can't declare a variable without declaring its **name**. It might not be your problem, but it's a real issue with your code.

Comment: I see what you want, you want to create a `List<Entity>` with the name of that list being the `PropertyName` of the `DataConsistencyModel`, if this is correct I'm pretty sure it's not possible.

Comment: Indeed.  If that's what you're intending to do, that's a limitation of c# (as well as a good chunk of other languages for that matter).

Comment: Could I use a dictionary `Dictionary<string, class>` ?

Comment: You can't use `class` as a value for a dictionary. You could go with `Dictionary<string, object>` if  you are dealing with instances, or when you are just dealing with types use: `Dictionary<string, Type>`

Answer (score 0):

Using a List of Dictionaries would be a useful workaround!

```
        var myObject = new List<Dictionary<string,object>>
        {
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"val1", 1},
                {"val2", true},
                {"val3", "String1"}
            },
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"val1", 2},
                {"val2", true},
                {"val3", "String2"}
            }
        };
        // you can add as many Values as you want
        myObject.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"val1", 2},
            {"val2", true},
            {"val3", "my new String"},
            {"val4", "my new String 2"}
        });
        // Use Keys to access values (Don't Forget casting)
        var output = (String) myObject[0]["val3"];
```